# How can I fix issue connecting Arduino with python?

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to configure python on my arduino. Ive followed like 10 tutorials but none of them are working. Ive tried to connect via pyserial. When I use pyserial, I simply get no response, here is the code.

I am trying to process data and code in python, then send data to arduino to run. I already downloaded the Firmata libraries on both, no issues there. I have also uploaded the arduino standard firmata sketch, no issues there.

Code being run on my python ide:

```
import serial
import time

Arduino = serial.Serial('com5',115200)
time.sleep(5)
while True:
    while (Arduino.inWaiting()==0):
        print("ur dumb")
        pass
    dataPacket = Arduino.readline()
    print(dataPacket)

Code being run on my Arduino IDE:

int count = 1;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.print(count);
  delay(1000);
  count = count+1;

}
```

Similary I've tried:

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

digital_input = board.get_pin('d:10:i')
led = board.get_pin('d:13:o')

while True:
    sw = digital_input.read()
    if sw is True:
        led.write(1)
    else:
        led.write(0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: In the first code, you're calling `.readline()` on the Python side, but you're never sending a newline character on the Arduino side, so the line never ends.  In the second code, perhaps you should print out exactly what value is being assigned to `sw` - it might be 0/1, in which case `sw is True` will never be true.

Comment: If that is the case, then shouldn't I at least be receiving one very long line? Do you know a better way to run python on arduino?

Comment: You could set a timeout on the Python `Serial` object, so that `.readline()` would eventually return even in the absence of a newline - or you could simply send a newline after each item of data from the Arduino side.

Comment: Change `Serail.print()` to `Serial.println()` to send a line (i.e. terminated with `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a more accessible python program here to work:

```
import serial                                                              
import time                                                                   
ArduinoUnoSerial = serial.Serial('com5',115200)                                                                   

while 1:         
    print (ArduinoUnoSerial.readline())
```

this will work with your Arduino program

> don't worry about the board no matter whether it is mega or uno or anything else ArduinoUnoSerial.readline() will work